# Environmental vars not vorking in browser in Next.js after deployment

Tags: node.js, github, next.js, vercel

In my Next.js `v.13.1.1` app encountered problem with env variables that work only locally.
The flow is

1. Open app in VS Code and start work
2. If change any .env file, I shut and reopen VS Code
3. Change app version number in .head file. Make a commit and push to GitHub, which is linked to Vercel
4. Open the browser, check if the app is loaded with updated version number, and look to the console to see if anything is logged out.

The code is
.env.local

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_WEB_CLIENT_ID=2341-2a29v1i7ov6.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

Now two files I do not know whether are necessary or not — just followed somebody's answer

.env.production

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_WEB_CLIENT_ID=2341-2a29v1i7ov6.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

.env.development

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_WEB_CLIENT_ID=2341-2a29v1i7ov6.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

As I said - do not know whether need it or not, same with next file:

next.config.js

```
 @type {import('next').NextConfig} 
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    images: { domains: ["images.unsplash.com", "wembleypark.com"] },
    env: {
        WEB_CLIENT_ID: process.env.WEB_CLIENT_ID,
    },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Here is where I consume varables:
_app.tsx

```
process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WEB_CLIENT_ID && console.log("next webclientid", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WEB_CLIENT_ID);
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ADMIN_DATA && console.log("next admin", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ADMIN_DATA);
    process.env.WEB_CLIENT_ID && console.log("webclientid", process.env.WEB_CLIENT_ID);

    return (
        <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WEB_CLIENT_ID as string}>
...
```

Perhaps the code is redundant, but I have revised few similar threads and applied most of solutions, however nothing works.

I also suspect that it could be commit/push/git issue. GitIgnore prevents .env files. I have only limited idea how building works.
I could try push without GitIgnore restrictions — but what later? These should not be exposed. Yes, I can remove them from GHPages immediately after (hopefully succesfull) build. But should I repeat the same after every code modification and commit/push?

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `.env` files are ignored, they are not pushed to `GitHub`, so during build on Vercel they are absent. You have to set them on Vercel in the project settings, as they say on the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#environment-variables-on-vercel):

> When deploying your Next.js application to [Vercel](https://vercel.com), Environment Variables can be configured in the [Project Settings](https://vercel.com/docs/projects/environment-variables?utm_medium=docs&utm_source=next-site&utm_campaign=next-website).

[image]

Comment: Great, I never looked closer to Vercel, thank you for that advise :)

Comment: Glad I could give the hint @Kiszuriwalilibori. Let us know whenever your problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you again, now it works like charm.  That is my first Next/Vercel project, so far everything worked as expected then have not bothered with configuration - it started without any, what is an advantage.